# How to rename file before saving it to database in django rest_framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin,mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin ):

```
serializer_class = userdataSerializer
queryset = UserData.objects.all()

lookup_field = 'id'


def get(self, request, id=None):
    if id:
        return self.retrieve(request)
    else:
        return self.list(request)

def post(self, request):

    return self.create(request)

def put(self, request, id=None):        
    return self.update(request, id)
```

////////////////////  models.py //////////////////////////

```
class UserData(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, default="", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
user_phn = models.IntegerField(default=0)
user_verification_id = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/documents', default="no-img.png")
user_linkedin_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
user_twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
user_cv = models.FileField(upload_to='users/cv', default="no-img.png")
user_about = models.CharField(max_length=500)
user_bal = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Userdata"


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

///////////////////////////// serializer.py ///////////////////////////

from rest_framework import serializers
from users.models import UserData
import uuid

## users serializer

class userdataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = UserData
    fields = ['user_phn','user_verification_id','user_linkedin_id','user_twitter_id','user_cv','user_about','user_bal','user_id']
```

I want to rename CV and image before saving it to database

Answer (score 3):

As you are using CreateModelMixin, you can add a perform_create function to your view function to customize the image and file names.

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.validated_data['user_verification_id'].name = 'foo_image_name'
    serializer.validated_data['user_cv'].name = 'foo_cv_name'
    serializer.save()
```

Comment: Great, I am glad it helped you.

Comment: Sorry but in need to have the file type first. how I can get the file extension because it  is saying cannot call save() after calling serialize.data

Ooopss I got it

Comment: You can call serializer.validated_data to check the file and image data.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename your file using the by assigning a function to your filefield like below.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # filename = TODO : logic to change your filename
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
```

and your model filefield declaration should be like below.

```
user_cv = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: this function user_directory_path(). do i need to create in seraializer.py or models.py???

Comment: In your model.py file.